# Magento 2 : Store Switcher In admin not working

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, store-view

> In Magento 2 admin side, I added store switcher in phtml file using this code.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->getToolbar()->addChild(
            'store_switcher',
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher'
        );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

> **So above code show store selection in phtml file as below,**

[image]

> When I select diffrent store from the list, then admin URL is change,
> but when I access store information in phtml like this `$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode()`

> **but it always return "default" not selected store code.**

**Can Any one have idea ?**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="admin-2columns-left">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="store_switcher">
                <action method="setUseConfirm">
                    <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already solve the problem.

Comment: but you can accept answer) or publish yours ;)